# CodeIgniter- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, paypal

I am new to codeigniter and I'm trying to integrate PayPal payment system for a project I have been working on. But the problem is when I'm trying to make an ajax call to make PayPal check out I am getting internal server error 500.

And when I open the controller I see error like this even though that file is still there in the folder.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(/home/*******/public_html/application/libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/Paypal.php

Line Number: 3
```

But this script is working perfectly fine in my local host where i don't have any htaccess. So, I am not sure what is going or or what to look for.

Comment: what is the root of your remote host? Are you sure it's '/home/*******/public_html/'?

Comment: yes i am sure .on top of that i m using php APPPATH for that

Comment: I'm not to sure then but maybe the answer on this page can help you out they have a really nice answer with a good explanation on how to solve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Are you sure the file `bootstrap.php` exists in the location it states (on the server)? The error implies that the file is missing.

Comment: yes its there i double checked it

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding your code is working fine in local and not working in production/live

if that is the case, go check permission to the file/folder if those are in vendor folder

Comment: i do not understand what you mean by vendor folder but if you asking if i have direct access to my public directory thought server file manger then no. i am using hostinger free service.only way to access file is though ftp